# Navbar won't collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm looking at this code and I just can't figure out what is the problem. When I shrink browser to test my navbar-collapse U only get links after pressing the button, my navbar stays exactly the same height! One small line appears under the navbar and that is it! Any help would be most appreciated!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse " role="navigation" id="navigacija">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">GsC</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data- target="#navHeaderCollapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navHeaderCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right list-inline" id="linkovi">
          <li><a href="index.html" id="homegl"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home">   
    </span></a> 
          </li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a> 
          </li>
          <li><a href="ourteam.html">OUR TEAM</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's due to a typo on the button. It looks like:

```
<button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data -target="#navHeaderCollapse">
```

But it should look like

```
<button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navHeaderCollapse">
```

there is an unwanted space in `data- target`. If you remove that it should work.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse " role="navigation" id="navigacija">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">GsC</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navHeaderCollapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navHeaderCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right list-inline" id="linkovi">
          <li><a href="index.html" id="homegl"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home">   
    </span></a> 
          </li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a> 
          </li>
          <li><a href="ourteam.html">OUR TEAM</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hello Ckujjer, thank you for your help. Unwanted space was not the issue. There was a glitch with too many id`s and styling in css. I am not sure why this is happening but when i add id to <nav the code doesnt work, but when i add <div in next line just for id <div id="navigacija"> everything works. Strange. I have picked up some nice info from you and altered my navbar. Thank you for that!